# Proof verification of the well-definedness of an map between a quotient of a free group and another free group and then showing it is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that F is a free group on $X$ and $Y\subset X$. I want to show that the map $f$ from $F/<Y>_n$ to the free group on $X-Y$ defined by taking the identity element to the identity element and taking $z_1^{a_1}z_2^{a_2}...z_m^{a_m}<Y>_n$ to $z_1^{a_1}z_2^{a_2}...z_m^{a_m}$, where $<Y>_n$ denotes the normal closure, and each $z_i$ is in $X-Y$ is well defined. My solution is as follows:

If $z_1^{a_1}z_2^{a_2}...z_m^{a_m}<Y>_n=w_1^{b_1}w_2^{b_2}...w_s^{b_s}<Y>_n$ where each $z_i, w_j$ is in $X-Y$ then each term must be equal as they are not in $Y$. Is it correct? If not, what possibly other map must I define and how must I prove its well-definedness?

Appendix: I found out how to define a homomorphism between them, and it is easy to see that it is an epimorphism. How can I show that it is a monomorphism as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd proceed differently:

All the fuzz about well-definedness tends to boil down to

> If $A,B$ are groups and $N\lhd A$ and $\pi\colon A/N$ is the canonical projection, then $\psi\mapsto \psi\circ \pi$ is a bijection between the set of homomoprhisms $A/N\to B$ and the set of those homomorphisms $\phi\colon A\to B$ with $N\le\ker\phi$. Put differentlx: For every homomoprhism $\phi\colon A\to B$ with $N\le\ker\phi$, there exists a unique homomorphism $\psi\colon A/N\to B$ with $\psi\circ \pi=\phi$.

One should show this once and only once in one's life, and I bet you already did.

With that in mind, we can proceed as follows:

By definition of free group $F$ on $X$, for every group $G$ and map $f\colon X\to G$, there exists exactly one group homomorphism $\phi\colon F\to G$ with $\phi|_X=f$.
If $G$ happens to be the free group on $X-Y$, we can consider $f\colon X\to G$ as follows:
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\in X-Y\\1&\text{if }x\in Y\end{cases}$$

By definition of $f$, we have $Y\subseteq \ker \phi$ for the homomorphism $\phi\colon F\to G$  defined this way.
As $\ker\phi$ is *some* normal subgroup that contains $Y$ and $N:=\langle Y\rangle_n$ is by definition the *smallest* normal subgroup containing $Y$, we conclude $N\le \ker\phi$.
But a group homomorphism $\phi\colon F\to G$ with $N\lhd F$ and $N\le \ker\phi$ induces a unique group homomorphism $\psi\colon F/N\to G$ with $\psi\circ\pi=\phi$, where $\pi\colon F\to F/N$ is the canonical projection.

Comment: I have a problem, why is  $\psi$ injective?

Comment: I think it is injective since if $x_1^{a_1}...x_n^{a_n}$ is in the kernal of $\phi$ then its image must have even length and so it is the product of members of $N$ since it is normal. Right?